# jquery autocomplete - Clickable appended items

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a autocomplete control which works when the first set of autocompleted "suggestions" are rendered from my custom data source.

I have a mechanism which detects when the scroll is at the very bottom, in which case additional data is loaded and appended to the autocomplete UL element.

```
// This loads more data when scroll bar reaches the bottom of autocomplete suggestion list.
$(".autocomplete ul", $MyForm).bind('scroll', function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.scrollTop() > maxScrollTopLength) {
                    maxScrollTopLength = $this.scrollTop();
                    if (!currentCallInProgress && maxScrollTopLength > $this[0].scrollHeight - $this.height() - settings.bottomScrollLength) {
                        skipToken += 1;
                        // search for suggestions based on scroll movement.
                        loadMoreItems(pageSearch.$query.val());
                    }
                }
            });
```

**The problem is this:**

The appended items are not clickable, although they appear in the list.
What am I doing wrong?

Note that in the method that handles the loading of the appended data items, there is no response object to call (it is called for the source: function).

*** Updated: ***

My autocomplete control implements source: like this:

```
source: function (request, callback) {
   loadData(request.term, callback);   
   // loadData basically makes an $.ajax call to retrieve data, and calls -
   // callback(results)
}
```

source: function (request, response) {

Answer (score 1):

in order to refresh the list of values of the autocomplete so that it contains the new values, and they are fully functional you can use a call like this...

```
$( "#myAutocompleteFieldId" ).autocomplete({
       source: initialValues.concat(newValues)
    });       
});
```

...rather then add the entries directly in the UL of the autocomplete. In this way the jquery ui library will know how to handle the new values correctly.
I have made a JSFiddle here to illustrate how this works : https://jsfiddle.net/n3p3epkc/
If you type in 'j' you will see entries from the initial list. When you type in 'ja' the list will be updated with additional values.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will soon test this out and give u the credit if it works!

Comment: Could you update your answer to include my scenario (where I am pulling additional data based on the scroll position)?

Comment: Can you setup a JSFiddle with how your code works now and I can debug it there? There are some parts that are missing and I am not sure how everything fits in place. In case of an ajax call you will need to update the source in the callback, after they are loaded from the server.

Comment: This is a typical autocomplete scenario, where the term the user types in is sent to a webservice, which returns a list of suggested results. The initial suggestion list works because it is being rendered BY autocomplete control via the response callback. However, additional suggestions are not rendered BY the control because the webservice is being called/handled by the scroll detection method.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice, elegant fix for my problem.
Basically I set a variable called "appending" to true when a scroll event invokes a search.

When search results are returned for "appending" results, I simply concat the list of items to a separate List.

The source: function is now modified to either do its usual new search OR render the full List of suggested items via the response callback.

In short, the source: function does 2 different things based on the state of the "appending" variable being true or false.

Hope this helps others.